# Why is .htaccess insecure by default to prevent unauthorized access?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I was browsing the web and came across the following:

> Source code, including config files, are stored in publicly accessible directories along with files that are meant to be downloaded (such as static assets). [...] You can use .htaccess to limit access. This is not ideal, because it is insecure by default, but there is no other alternative.

[Source: owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Framework_issues)

Sometimes I use the following code to prevent access from a specific directory:

```
// contents of .htaccess
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from none
```

On servers where there is access outside of the webroot there is obviously less need to prevent access to folders/files with .htaccess.

Can someone explain why they write ".htaccess is insecure by default" and what are alternative ways to prevent access to certain files on a regular LAMP-stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is not a complete security solution. It doesn't protect you from ddos, sniffing, or man in the middle (when using auth) without SSL.

As far as denying access to specific files, it's generally fine. The scenarios under which it would fail to do so are scenarios where there has already been a successful exploit somewhere else. Since any files in the directory have to be readable by the process owner, the files are only superficially secured by .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks David! Appreciate your response on my first stackoverflow question ;)

Could you possibly elaborate on ways to protect files within the web root (in case there is no access possible outside)?

Comment: You can implement rules similar to .htaccess at another application/network layer in front of your Apache server, but it's not typically necessary. 

The takeaway should to be make sure your application is hosted in an environment with reasonable protection from man in the middle (always use SSL!), ddos (lots of good hosts offer protection), and of course keep applications/packages all well up to date and use security scans to identify and address weak points.

Comment: Thanks David. I appreciate your advice. I'll investigate in this matter further to enhance security of websites/apps that are on a shared server with limited security possibilities!